# libudev.so.1 not found when trying to run spotify

Tags: spotify

I am trying to run Spotify on Ubuntu 12.04. It used to work some time ago, when I tried to start it today, I got the following error:

```
spotify: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

how to fix it?

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libudev1
```

which however gives an error saying that it does not exist (any more)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## WARNING!

> THIS SOLUTION **BREAKS UNITY** ON RECENT VERSIONS OF UBUNTU WHICH MAKES UBUNTU **UNABLE TO BOOT**. YOU PROBABLY DON'T WANT TO TRY IT UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING.
>
> **PLEASE PROCEED WITH CAUTION.**

---

---

---

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS do following:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev0
```

Then you create a symlink to the file as following (64bit):

> **PLEASE PROCEED WITH CAUTION!!**
>     sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1

If you are using a 32bit:

> **PLEASE PROCEED WITH CAUTION!!**
>     sudo ln -sf /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1

Now Spotify should recognize the correct library.
If this doesn't work, please post back and I'll try to help you further :)

Comment: This worked, spotify starts without problems now.

Comment: It should be noted that the Spotify devs [have acknowledged this issue](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Spotify-0-9-17-for-GNU-Linux-and-the-upcoming-1-x-beta/m-p/1075006#M119549) and have promised a fix in the near future.

Comment: I can also add that you should delete the symlink libudev.so.1 as soon as the update arrives. If a program that use libudev.so.1 isn't compatible with libudev.so.0 something could break. This is only a quickfix and a temporary solution for your problem.

Comment: @LarsMartinsen that command (`sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1`) broke unity for me. No login screen. How do I reverse this link?

Comment: @mina michael, shoul've read your comment first... :(

Comment: @AdriansNetlis it's reversible but it needs work

Comment: @AdriansNetlis the command just breaks a link. we simple need to re-establish it via command line. try to join me in chat whenever you can